# What is this fruit found in a market in Uyuni, Bolivia at the end of December 2019? (orange skin, 4cm, white flesh)

Tags: species-identification, fruit

What is this fruit found in a market in Uyuni, Bolivia at the end of December 2019?

[image]

Fruit diameter: ~4 cm. Seed: large, spherical, black. Flesh: white. Taste: sweet but not as sweet as a lychee.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the name: it appears to be [Garcinia humilis, known commonly as achachairú or achach](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garcinia_humilis):

> Garcinia humilis, known commonly as achachairú or achacha, is a small, prolifically-fruiting tree related to the mangosteen. It grows in the southern part of the Amazon basin in the central area of Bolivia, but has recently been planted on a commercial scale in Burdekin, Australia.

That matches the area, appearance and season.